# Nodejs - Using data in and out of callback functions

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am new to nodejs, and I was trying to write a simple http server that respond to requests after looking up a PostGreSQL server. My -not working as planned - code, looks like this:

```
var http = require("http");
var pg = require("pg");
var conString =     "postgres://user:-----@--.--.--.--:5432/dbname";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

function getusers(username,password){
    return client.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log("Failed to connect to PGSQL Server");
            return "Failed";
        }
        else{
            return client.query('SELECT * FROM user_data.user_data', function(err, result) {
            if(err) {
              return console.error('error running query', err);
            }
            console.log(result.rows[0]);
            client.end();
          });
    }
});
// return "duh";
}

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain

   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   // response.end(request.headers['username']+"::"+request.headers['password']);
   response.end(getusers(request.headers['username'],request.headers['password']));
}).listen(8082);
```

So, while trying to write the server, I faced this problem: I either wanted to execute the query and use the callback function to return the response, or I could somehow use the results of the query outside, to process them as I wish and send the appropriate response. However, I cannot somehow pass the request parameter in the query callback function, and I cannot - as far as I know - return the query result from the `client.query` function, so as to use the said function in a callback fashion from another function.

Do you have any advice on that? Let me know if you need any clarification in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood how those callbacks works.

`client.connect` is async. This means that when you retrieve the "returned" value of this method, you cannot be sure that it executed. This is why your getUser function returns no result, and even before executing the rest of your methods.

The callback given is used as you would, to execute other functions after this one is executed, so that you can chain them. But it also mean that you cannot use the `return` keyword as you would in a sync. function.

What I would advice you to do is to **pass a callback function to your `getusers` function**. This way you would be able to call it like that :

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    //whatever
    getusers(username, function(err,res) {
        //This callback is executing after all of the getusers function is executed.
        // getusers calls it with two argument, one is the result to send, the other errors if any.
        response.end(res);
   }
}).listen(8082);
```

This also means that you need to modify your current `getusers` so that it takes one more argument (the callback function) **and call it once your requests to the db are finished**

Comment: Instead of returning your result you need to return them by calling the callback function that you give to your functions.

Comment: But I don't get how to "return" the result from inside the function `client.query` called. At least to use it on another callback function. Or are the return statements fine and I just must use them in a callback function to work as I wish?

Comment: I tested and used `response` as a parameter to `getusers`, and I can use it inside the call-backed functions, even if it's not passed directly, and that pretty much unties my hands.